# Distributing integral into product of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I would like to know if $$\int_{x_1} \left[ \left[ \int_{x_2} g_1(x_1,x_2) dx_2 \right] \cdot \left[ \int_{x_3} g_2(x_1,x_3)dx_3 \right] \right] dx_1 \stackrel{?}{=} \left[ \int_{x_1} \int_{x_2} g_1(x_1,x_2) dx_2 dx_1 \right] \cdot \left[ \int_{x_1} \int_{x_3} g_2(x_1,x_3) dx_3 dx_1 \right]$$
I don't need a proof, but maybe a pointer to what rule of integration would show this to be true (or not true).
I have tried to expand the left hand side (LHS) of the equation above as follows
$$ \text{LHS} = \int_{x_1} \left[ \int_{x_3} \int_{x_2} g_1(x_1,x_2) g_2(x_1,x_3) dx_2 dx_3 \right] dx_1 $$
Simplifying further, we get
$$ \text{LHS} = \int_{x_1} \int_{x_3} \int_{x_2} g_1(x_1,x_2) g_2(x_1,x_3) dx_2 dx_3 dx_1 $$

Again, in summary, are there properties of integrals, or is there a proof which shows that the LHS equals the right hand side (RHS)?  The RHS is repeated below for clarity.

$$ \text{RHS} = \left[ \int_{x_1} \int_{x_2} g_1(x_1,x_2) dx_2 dx_1 \right] \cdot \left[ \int_{x_1} \int_{x_3} g_2(x_1,x_3) dx_3 dx_1 \right] $$

It is safe to assume that the functions $g_1(x_1,x_2)$ and $g_2(x_1,x_3)$ are integratable over the regions specified.

Thanks!

Comment: Essentially, your first line reads $\int_{x_1} G_2(x_1) G_3(x_1) \, \mathrm{d}x_1$. Now use partial integration.

Comment: Your comment made me realize I specified the question incorrectly.  I've respecified the question properly.  The $g$ functions are not necessarily the same, so they should be indexed.  Thanks for the hint on partial integration, I need to understand whether that still applies in light of me correcting the question.

Comment: If you had finite integration intervals and the identity as integrands, it would turn into something like $\Delta x_1 \Delta x_2 \Delta x_3 = (\Delta x_1 \Delta x_2)(\Delta x_1 \Delta x_3) = (\Delta x_1)^2 \Delta x_2 \Delta x_3$ so I think your equation does not hold. Alteratively I could argue with units which would not match ($L^3$ vs. $L^4$).

Comment: @mvw Good point, I didn't think about that.  I suppose then that if the LHS was $\int_{x_1} \int_{x_1} \int_{x_2} \int_{x_3} g_1(x_1,x_2) g_2(x_1,x_3) dx_2 dx_3 dx_1 dx_1$ then the RHS would equal the LHS?  I guess that doesn't prove it works for all $g_1$ and $g_2$, just when $g_1$ and $g_2$ is identity, but its a start.

Comment: @mvw What do you mean by the units not matching? Referencing $L^3$ vs $L^4$?  I'm not tracking there.

Comment: If this was a physical meaningful equation, like e.g. the $x_i$ being physical lengths, then the units on the LHS must match the units on the RHS. If the lengths were measured in $m$, the equation would equate $m^3$ on the LHS and $m^4$ on the right hand side. This is not allowed. (See [Dimensional analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis))

Comment: Maybe should look into [Fubini-Tonelli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) first.

Comment: @mvw Thanks, your dimensionality argument makes sense.  I'll take a look at Fubini's Theorem as well.